# Android Google Maps works on emulator but not on real device

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2

I try to get working signed release apk to work on real device. I have created release certificate with release API key which I put in my release google_maps_api.xml file. In manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

When I generated signed release apk and install it and run in emulator maps loads and works but when I try to do the same on real device maps does not even load.

Comment: Which keystore you use to generate SHA1 key? Debug KeyStore or Release Debug keystore?

Comment: please check SHA1 on SignApk that added in google console

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar SHA1 matches in google console.

Comment: @Shane I created release certificate and use it to get release API key and then I created signed release apk with that certificate.

Comment: Just further to mi14chals answer (I dont have enough rep to add a comment to that answer), I found the signing key under setup > app integrity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Now fingerprint of release certificate is useless. To get map working you need to go to Google Play Console -> choose app -> Release management -> App signing and use fingerprint from App signing certificate.